# Why my code does not iterate over all the pages of a website(web scraping)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I want to web scrape the "search:pc" part of the website called jumia. I wanted to iterate over all the pages ,but unfortunetly it didn't work , I don't why it overwrites the file while it is outside the loop and by using:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="replace") as writer:
        pop.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet1"
```

instead of:

```
with open(f"output.xlsx" ,"a") :
    with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx") as writer:
        pop.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="sheet2")
```

but it results in an error:

```
File "c:\Users\hp\Desktop\python_projects\test3.py", line 40, in <module>
    find_computers()
  File "c:\Users\hp\Desktop\python_projects\test3.py", line 33, in find_computers
    with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="replace") as writer:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 61, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1263, in __init__  
    self._handles = get_handle(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 872, in get_handle
    handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output.xlsx'
```

this is my actual code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import openpyxl
from bs4 import Tag


def find_computers():
  n=1
  while n<=50:
    html_text=requests.get(f"https://www.jumia.ma/catalog/?q=pc&page={n}#catalog-listing").text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html_text,"lxml")
    computers=soup.find_all("a",class_="core")
    df={"price": [],"original price": [],"promo":[]}
    computer_name_list=[]
    for computer in computers:
        computer_name=computer.find("h3",class_="name").text.strip()
        price=computer.find("div",class_="prc").text.strip()
        original_price_element=computer.find("div",class_="old")
        original_price=original_price_element.text.strip() if isinstance(original_price_element, Tag) else "N/A"
        promo_element = computer.find("div", class_="bdg _dsct _sm")
        promo = promo_element.text.strip() if isinstance(promo_element, Tag) else "N/A"
        df["price"].append(price)
        df["original price"].append(original_price)
        df["promo"].append(promo)
        computer_name_list.append(computer_name)
    n+=1
  pop=pd.DataFrame(df,index=computer_name_list)
  pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center')
  with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx") as writer:
      pop.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="sheet2")
  


if __name__=="__main__":
  while True:
        find_computers()
        time_s = 10
        time.sleep(6 * time_s)
```

Comment: Your second paragraph of code above opens the file and then opens it again as Excel. This may cause problems

Comment: thanks but it doesn't solve the problem ,it stills shows the data of the last page(page50))

Comment: Would you really write an empty DataFrame? Please correct your indention and unused imports.!

Comment: my project isn't yet completed ,i have other uses for them, thanks!

Comment: why is it empty?

Comment: Your code works fine on my computer. Check for permission in the folder you are trying to write the XLSX to

Comment: @gtomer ,my code works but the problem is that it only shows in excel the info of he last page of the search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works also fine for me, so just in addition to avoid the creation of empty dataframe and appending in your loop an example, how to store results and create dataframe after collection:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, time

def find_computers():
    n=1
    data = []
    while n<=5:
        html_text=requests.get(f"https://www.jumia.ma/catalog/?q=pc&page={n}#catalog-listing").text
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html_text,"lxml")
        computers=soup.find_all("a",class_="core")

        for computer in computers:

            data.append({
                'name':computer.find("h3",class_="name").text.strip(),
                'price':computer.find("div",class_="prc").text.strip(),
                'original_price':computer.find("div",class_="old").text.strip() if computer.find("div",class_="old") else None,
                'promo_element':computer.find("div", class_="bdg _dsct _sm").text.strip() if computer.find("div", class_="bdg _dsct _sm") else None

            })
        n+=1

        time_s = 10
        time.sleep(6 * time_s)

    return data

if __name__=="__main__":

    data = find_computers()
    with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx") as writer:
        pd.DataFrame(data).to_excel(writer,sheet_name="sheet1")
```

Comment: thanks ,but i want it to iterate over all the dispo pages(50):

Comment: for example:html_text=requests.get(f"https://www.jumia.ma/catalog/?q=pc&page={1}#catalog-listing").text, then, html_text=requests.get(f"https://www.jumia.ma/catalog/?q=pc&page={2}#catalog-listing").text , and so on

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the df initiation line outside the loop. See example:

```
def find_computers():
    n=1
    df={"price": [],"original price": [],"promo":[]}
```

Comment: I agree, otherwise the dataframe will be emptied and overwritten again and again.

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues is that you can't append a df/sheet to a *non-existing* Excel file.

You should either have a pre-created file, or create one before starting the process :

```
from pathlib import Path

OUTPUT_FP = "output.xlsx"
if not Path(OUTPUT_FP).exists():
    pd.DataFrame().to_excel(OUTPUT_FP)
```

And here is a proposition to save the computers info (*of each page*) at real-time in a separate ss:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, time

KW = "pc"

URL = "https://www.jumia.ma/catalog/?q={kw}&page={pn}#catalog-listing"

def find_computers(sleep):
    kw_found = True; n=1
    
    while kw_found:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL.format(kw=KW, pn=n)).text, "lxml")
                
        data = []
        for c in soup.find_all("a", class_="core"):
            data.append(
                {
                    "name": c.find("h3", class_="name").get_text(strip=True),
                    "price": c.find("div", class_="prc").get_text(strip=True),
                    "original price": op.get_text(strip=True) if (op:= c.find("div", class_="old")) else "N/A",
                    "promo": pr.get_text(strip=True) if (pr:=c.find("div", class_="bdg _dsct _sm")) else "N/A"
                }
            )
    
        with pd.ExcelWriter(OUTPUT_FP, engine="openpyxl",
            mode="a", if_sheet_exists="replace"
        ) as writer:
            pd.DataFrame(data).set_index("name").to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"Sheet{n}")
            
        kw_found = soup.find("h2").get_text(strip=True) != f'Aucun résultat pour "{KW}".'
        
        n+=1
        
        time.sleep(sleep)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    find_computers(sleep=2)
```

Preview (*output.xlsx with 2 pages*) :

[image]